# Closing a Windows Form, using the Close Window button, when a Validation Message is showing

Tags: winforms

I have a Windows form that has a validation event on a textBox so that if the value of that TextBox is a value that already exists it triggers a validation error.

```
    private void txtUsername_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        var alreadyExists = _logic.UserIdExists(txtUsername.Text.Trim());

        if(alreadyExists)
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(txtUsername, "This Userid already exists, please choose an alternative");
            e.Cancel = true;
        }                       
    }

    private void txtUsername_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        errorProvider1.SetError(txtUsername, "");
    }


        this.txtUsername.Validating += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(this.txtUsername_Validating);
        this.txtUsername.Validated += new System.EventHandler(this.txtUsername_Validated);
```

This results in an error image appearing next to that textBox along with a tooltip error message.

If I try and close the application, using the Close button at the top of the window, at this time I cannot as the above Event keeps firing even when I try and close the window (due to me taking focus away from the Text box).

Is there a way of closing the window, without resorting to creating an additional Close button on the form?

Comment: have you tried giving the focus back to the main window after the textBox is shown?

Comment: @TheMri I'm not sure exactly what you mean. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: A simple workaround is to use a `bool` field (e.g., `bool IsFormClosing`), set to `true` just by the `FormClosing()` handler. Set the validation handlers to execute only when `IsFormClosing` is `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description, you want to maintain the default auto-validation behavior yet allow the Form to be closed using the title bar close button.  I have observed that the Form.Closing event is raised in such a circumstance, however its argument Cancel property is preset to `true`.  A simple solution is to handle this event and set `e.Cancel = false`.  Implement any logic in the handler that you deem necessary.

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing) e.Cancel = false;
}
```